# how can i rewrite this code to make an object fall from top of canvas and when hits bottom it resets at top

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to implement a group of objects that will fall from the top of the canvas in random spots, and then when they hit the bottom of the canvas they respawn at the top of the canvas. Ideally, I want to change this code in the future to use sprites that will fall from the top of the canvas and explode when they hit the bottom of the canvas but then respawn again at the top.

I have the bellow code that works when the mouse is pressed but I would like to rewrite this code so the event happens automatically without the mouse needed to be pressed to make the objects fall.

see code below.

```
var x, y;
var particle = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(720, 400);
  // Starts in the middle
  x = width / 2;
  y = height;
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  if (mouseIsPressed){
  stroke(50);
  fill(100);
  ellipse(x, y, 24, 24);
  }
  x = x + 0;
  // Moving up at a constant speed
  y = y + 2;
  
  // Reset to the bottom
  if (y >= height) {
    y = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`mousePressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed) to add new particles to the list. The particles are added at the current mouse position (`mouseX`, `mouseY`). Move and draw the particles in a loop:

```js
var particles = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(720, 400);
}

function mousePressed() {
    particles.push([mouseX, mouseY]);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    stroke(50);
    for (let i=0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        particles[i][1] += 2;
        if (particles[i][1] > height) {
            particles[i][1] = 0;
        }
        fill(100);
        ellipse(particles[i][0], particles[i][1], 24, 24);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can spawn the particles with a time interval. Get the number of milliseconds (thousandths of a second) since starting the sketch with [`millis()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/millis). The y-coordinate of a new particle is 0 and the x-coordinate is [`random()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random):

```js
var particles = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(720, 400);
}

function mousePressed() {
    particles.push([mouseX, mouseY]);
}

function draw() {
    let max_no_of_particles = 40;
    let expected_no_of_praticles = min(max_no_of_particles, millis() / 100);
    if (particles.length < expected_no_of_praticles) {
        particles.push([random(12, width-12), 0]);
    }

    background(0);
    stroke(50);
    for (let i=0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        particles[i][1] += 2;
        if (particles[i][1] > height) {
            particles[i][1] = 0;
        }
        fill(100);
        ellipse(particles[i][0], particles[i][1], 24, 24);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your response rabbid76, I was trying to make this example work without the need to used a mouse press function. i would like the particles to simply fall by themselves without having to mouse press or any other button event.  would you be able to redo this code without the mouse pressed please?

Comment: @Yakob So how do you want to add new particles? By chance?

Comment: I have seen this done where objects fall from the top of the canvas at random positions without any need of a mouse being clicked to make the objects drop .

Comment: @Yakob Should that happen with a time interval?

Comment: that could work, im just not sure how I can implement that as I'm still fairly new to coding

Comment: @Yakob I've extended the answer.

Comment: thankyou so much just what i was after :)